# How to Watch $scope variable in parent window scope from child popup or window

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to SPA. Could you please suggest some best solution in angulajs , how to watch scope variables of parent window from child window or popup.

I have scenario to update child popup window based on value changed in parent scope variable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post all relevant code?

Comment: Please add code in jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: It is very unlikely that anyone can offer a solution without a [mcve] to work from.  However, logically, in a Single Page Application, you don't generally use popup windows, since then the Application is no longer a Single Page.